# Silex micro-framework and Twig: enable debug

Tags: php, twig, silex

**My question: How do I permit use of `debug` in Twig templates within Silex?**

---

I'm playing around with the Silex micro-framework (a PHP framework that leverages Symfony).

When using the Twig template system with it I wanted to output a particular object. Normally I would do this with `var_dump($app);` and in Twig with `{% debug app %}`.

My problem is getting debug (and setting Silex's own debug to `true` does not help with Twig) to work with Silex. Out of the box a call to `debug` will result in an error message:

```
Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown tag name "debug" in...
```

The call to debug looks like this:

```
{% debug app %}
```

I have found references to how to configure Twig's config.yml file to correctly use `debug` but Silex does not use a config file for Twig.

Silex does say you can set options via passing an associative array to `twig.options` and while Twig docs say you can pass an environment option like:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
```

Trying to pass it in Silex like:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.options' => array('debug' => true),
));
```

Does not work. Is this the wrong sort of option? Simply incorrect formatting? I've no idea and nothing I have tried works.

I sense myself getting into "wheel spinning" mode so I am asking here on SO in hopes that I can move on to more productive work this morning. :)

(ugh... how's that for a hyper-specific StackOverflow question?)

---

**Solution:** (all this just to get `var_dump` like functionality... oh my): This was a bit of a pain in the butt, to be honest, and the Silex docs were of no help whatsoever in discovering this but here is what I had to do to get this to work.

First load the Twig autoloader:

```
$app['autoloader']->registerPrefixes(array(
    'Twig_Extensions_'  => array(__DIR__.'/vendor/Twig-extensions/lib')));
```

Why do you have to register it this way? No idea. How does it actually find the autoloader? No idea. But it works.

Register the provider and set the debug option:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path'         => __DIR__.'/views',
    'twig.class_path'   => __DIR__.'/vendor/Twig/lib',
    'twig.options'      => array('debug' => true), //<-- this is the key line to getting debug added to the options
));
```

And finally (the best part):

```
$oldTwigConfiguration = isset($app['twig.configure']) ? $app['twig.configure']: function(){};
$app['twig.configure'] = $app->protect(function($twig) use ($oldTwigConfiguration) {
    $oldTwigConfiguration($twig);
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug());
});
```

To be honest, I think that's enough Silex for me.

Credit for this solution goes to [Nerdpress.](http://nerdpress.org/2011/11/21/enable-twig-extensions-in-silex/)

---

*ninja edit: a year and a half later I have to say that Silex was a dud for me. I have been using [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com) for all micro-framework needs and it is fantastic. Gets the job done quickly, cleanly, simply and easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I completely removed the old answer to show the output from a little example-app I built:

composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "silex/silex": "1.*",
    "twig/twig": "1.*",
    "twig/extensions": "*"
  }
}
```

app.php:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/.composer/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/views',
    'twig.options' => array('debug' => true)
));
$app['twig']->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug());

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('debug_test.twig', array('app' => $app));
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: $app['debug']=true was already set and your example of setting debug for just Twig is essentially the same thing I have that is not working. I edited my example to show more complete code but it's basically the same thing you have.

Comment: You are right, I never used debugging in Twig before, therefore I didn't notice. A quick run through returned the message: Unknown tag name "debug" in ... which made me realise it is probably provided by an extension, and voilá a quick search on google returned the above mentioned result ;)

Comment: Nice find, your "Google Fu" is better than mine. I had to change `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug()` to `Twig_Extension_Debug()`or it couldn't find it but in the end it still fails in the same way.

Comment: You have to add twig_extensions to your project; when you use composer you can do it by adding "twig/extensions" to your "require" otherwise add https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions and don't forget to add the path to the autoloader

Comment: Thanks. I found a complete solution but your advice helped point the way.

Comment: Side note: the twig service provider already registers app as a global, you don't have to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while now so I did a small update to the accepted answer, you can use the new extend method of Pimple:

composer.json:

```
"silex/silex": "~1.3",
"twig/twig": "^1.23",
"symfony/twig-bridge": "^2.7",
"twig/extensions": "^1.3"
```

index.php (front controller)

```
/*
* config
*/
//...
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
        'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../templets',
        'twig.options' => array('debug' => true),
    )
);
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
    return $twig;
}));
//...


/*
* some static page
*/
$app->get('/', function () use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig');
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

for silex ^2.2 using pimple 3 the share() has been removed so use:

```
$app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
    return $twig;
});
```